# Is possible to programmatically scale Azure instances?

Tags: c#, azure

Are there some Azure APIs that allow me to access the scaling functionalities from my C# code in Visual Studio? 
For example, I need to scale from 2 to 5 instances when some football matches end, and go back to 2 after 1 hour.

Comment: Look at the Azure auto scale features. And no, it is not possible.

Comment: Powershell is full of functionality for this type of stuff.  Not quite C#/VS, but not really all that far off either (and there's a lot that can be done in C# with the Azure SDK, but I'm pretty sure powershell offers a more robust API).

Comment: Scale instances of *what*? Web apps? Cloud services?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath Why do you say it's not possible?

Comment: Check into CloudMonix @ http://cloudmonix.com - its a 3rd party product, but allows to scale based on a ton of various very custom criteria.  Disclaimer: I'm affiliated with the product

Answer (score 0):

This indeed possible using [The Autoscaling Application Block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh680892(v=pandp.50).aspx), that enables to auto-scale using custom metrics. Nevertheless, note that this library is no longer maintained.

You may want to also read the updated [Autoscaling guidance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/best-practices-auto-scaling/#configure-autoscaling-for-an-azure-solution), which also describes the Autoscaling Application Block mentioned above.