# Azure App Services - Manage scaling from within the application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, autoscaling

I have a application hosted in Azure App Services where I'm running some jobs, the amount of jobs varies and the queue can be anywhere from 1 to 20 000 at a time. I'm using Hangfire to run these jobs.

I'm looking for a way to scale the App Services based on my own rules, I have tried scaling using the standard rules based on performance but not all the jobs use much resources so the rules do not quite work out.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you wrapping this jobs under a webjob? or are you deploying this code as part of a bigger app? Also have you looked at Azure Functions? they might be a better fit for this than running them in the back of your app.

Comment: I'm deploying this as part of the bigger app, I haven't looked at Azure Functions yet, will look at those, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking for a way to scale the App Services based on my own rules, I have tried scaling using the standard rules based on performance but not all the jobs use much resources so the rules do not quite work out.

Per my understanding, if the autoscale (scale out) for multiple instances could not meet your requirement, I assumed that you could programmatically scale up or scale out your app service plan based on your custom rules. You could access [Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/appserviceplans#AppServicePlans_CreateOrUpdate) REST API for app service plan with Azure AD authentication. For more details, you could refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747886/is-it-possible-to-scale-azure-app-services-programmatically).

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I'm looking for