# Azure autoscale - anticipate autoscale manually

Tags: azure, scaling, autoscaling

We have an autoscale based on **CPU percentage average**.

Sometimes I know when the CPU will increase and I'd like to anticipate the VM deploy.

Is there a way to start the **autoscale** manually (but NOT disabling autoscale) using, for example, an API call?

Thank you,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to scale Azure app services programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747886/is-it-possible-to-scale-azure-app-services-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple soluzione using Azure CLI:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-create-and-manage-cli

This is the command:

```
az login
. . .
. . .
az vmss scale --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myScaleSet --new-capacity 4
```

very easy ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you know when the CPU will increase, have you considered setting up autoscale based on a schedule?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/tutorial-autoscale-performance-schedule