# How to programmatically scale Azure Cloud Service (classic) roles

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-management-api

Based on this how-to for scaling Azure app services programmatically:
[Is it possible to scale Azure app services programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747886/is-it-possible-to-scale-azure-app-services-programmatically),
I am trying to recreate this for Azure Cloud Services (classic), using the Azure.Management.Compute.ComputeManagementClient.

This is what I have so far. It works to a point, but I can never get my cloud services listed from the API:

```
Dim credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(Client_Id, clientSecret, tenant_Id, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
Dim client = New Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.ComputeManagementClient(credentials)
client.SubscriptionId = subscription_id
Dim servicesclient = client.CloudServices
Dim cloudservices = servicesclient.ListWithHttpMessagesAsync("MyResourceGroupName").Result.Body
```

Everything seems to work as expected to this point. If I put in the *wrong* resource group name, I get an error that the resource group does not exist. But when I put in the *right* resource group name, the expected list of cloud services comes back empty. It's possible there is some sort of permissioning issue, although I have checked that fairly carefully. Or is the CloudServices API here different than my 'classic' cloud services? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: I think the use of sdk needs to be used strictly in accordance with the document. If you are not very familiar with the document, it is not recommended to use the sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also recommand you use restapi to scale your roles.

I don't find offical restapi [on this site](https://resources.azure.com/). I found scale roles api by F12 when I click `save` button.

## Tips

*If you need other restapi functions, you can also use this method to find them quickly when the official api is not found.*

[image]

> **PATCH** Method 
>  https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<your_subscriptions>/resourceGroups/<your_resourcegroup_name>/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/<your_cloud_service_name>/slots/production/roles/WebRole1?api-version=2016-04-01
> **Header**
> Content-Type:application/json
> **Body:**
> {"sku":{"name":"Standard_D1_v2","tier":"Standard","capacity":2}}
>  **Auth**
> Bear Token

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had a suspicion that there was some sort of back door way to do it, but was hoping to avoid it. However if it is the only way, I will give it a try and see if I can get this to work.