# Scale Out Azure App Service Web App with C# programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

We have an Azure App Service Web App that we want to scale out based on certain criteria.  I've seen that this is possible using the "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Websites" package based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747886/is-it-possible-to-scale-azure-app-services-programmatically) that has been asked back in 2017 but these packages are now deprecated.  Is it possible to do this now in .NET?

Comment: did you try https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager.AppService ?  it is suggested as alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to scale out my app service plan using new package `Azure.ResourceManager.AppService` using GitHub Code.

Thanks @[azure-sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Azure.ResourceManager_1.7.0/sdk/websites/Azure.ResourceManager.AppService/samples/Generated/Samples) and [dvbb](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.ResourceManager_1.7.0/sdk/websites/Azure.ResourceManager.AppService/samples/Generated/Samples/Sample_AppServicePlanCollection.cs) for the code.

**Note:- Use .NET 7.0 or higher for this code**

Below code worked for me:

**`Program.cs`:**

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Models;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;
using Azure.ResourceManager.AppService;
using Azure.ResourceManager.AppService.Models;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main()
        {

            TokenCredential credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
            ArmClient client = new ArmClient(credential);


            string subscriptionId = "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx";
            string ResourceGroupName = "resourcegroupename";
            ResourceIdentifier resourceGroups = ResourceGroupResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId, ResourceGroupName);
            ResourceGroupResource resourceGroup = client.GetResourceGroupResource(resourceGroups);


            AppServicePlanCollection collection = resourceGroup.GetAppServicePlans();


            string name = "asp-vivekchatgpt";
            AppServicePlanData update_data = new AppServicePlanData(AzureLocation.EastUS)
            {
                Sku = new AppServiceSkuDescription()
                {
                    Name = "P2V3",
                    Tier = "Premium v3",
                    Capacity = 2,
                },
                Kind = "app",
            };
            ArmOperation<AppServicePlanResource> operation = await collection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, name, update_data);
            AppServicePlanResource result = operation.Value;

            AppServicePlanData resourceData = result.Data;

            Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded on id: {resourceData.Id}");
        }
    }
}
```

**`ConsoleApp1.csproj`:**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.10.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.ResourceManager" Version="1.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.ResourceManager.AppService" Version="1.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**`Output`:**

**Initial App Service Plan**

[image]

**After executing code:**

[image]

**Scaled Out App Service Plan**

[image]

Comment: This is working perfectly, thank you.

Comment: I am glad It helped. :)