# Scale Azure AppService / WebApp instance count using Azure.ResourceManager

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I created a C# Azure function that is supposed to run every five minutes and depending on the data volume retrieved from DB, I am trying to scale the instance count of an already running App Service/Web App.

I am trying to use Azure.ResourceManager and Azure.ResourceManager.AppService nuget packages to achieve this:

```
        ArmClient client = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
        ResourceGroupResource resourceGroup =
            client.GetDefaultSubscription().GetResourceGroup(ResourceGroupName);
```

but haven't found a way to use ResourceGroupResource instance to scale the app service

Comment: There is an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77310645/scale-out-azure-app-service-web-app-with-c-sharp-programmatically

Comment: @Camil-P Did the thread help?

Comment: @VivekVaibhavShandilya Yup, it definitely did. Thanks a lot, not sure how I missed the already existing thread...